# Can I disable sql trigger inside the same trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

**Can I disable SQL Trigger inside the same trigger during the execution of the trigger?**

***I am trying to update a column by trigger which fires on update of the same column***.
But the rows are different.

For example if row1 of column1 changes, then row 2 and row3 of column1 will change depending on row1.column1 value.

If my trigger fires on first update of row1.column1 then my trigger fires and updates other rows of the same column. As the column value update again,the trigger fires again.  This may create a never ending loop (I assume)

So I want to disable the trigger during the time of execution of the same trigger.I don't want to use INSTEAD OF trigger as there is a possibility of rollback of the update statement depending on some other database transactions.
I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DISABLE TRIGGER triggername
ALTER TABLE tablename ENABLE TRIGGER triggername
```

to disable and enable the trigger but getting error when execute update statemant

Msg 2801, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Triggername, Line 47
The definition of object 'Triggername' has changed since it was compiled.
The statement has been terminated.

Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: Looks like SQL Server, so why the [tag:mysql] tag? Also, disabling the trigger is definitely the wrong route to go down unless your database is only designed to support *one* user. I'm not sure what your point about `instead of` and rollbacks was meant to be.

Comment: Is your data `normal`?  It seems like having data depend on other records in the same table is a bad idea, and you are now seeing why.

Comment: I guess if the update statement on row1 fails, INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger will fire and will change row2 and row3 value. I am using transactionscope in entity framework to update row1. as well as some other tables of the database.